# Confirm dialog box with anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html

My friend done this below coding for custom control

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('id','msg');">click</a>
```

now i want to show confirm dialog box while click this anchor link.

Is it possible?. i want to write script as inline.

Comment: Create a function (e.g. `confirm()`) where you do your according stuff and call it from `__doPostBack()`.

Comment: @Christoph There already is a confirm function in javascript.

Comment: @dystroy If you want to use the standard ugly builtin confirm-dialog, yes.

Comment: Using elegant confirm dialog is more work and requires some javascript/html/css knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this :

```
<a href="javascript:if (window.confirm('Really?')){__doPostBack('id','msg');};">click</a>
```

---

But at some point, you'd want to stop using only inline code and have a look at other clearer ways to add javascript in your code.

You may use a script block like this in the HEAD of your HTML file :

```
<script>
    function doOnClick(){
       if (window.confirm('Really?')){
           __doPostBack('id','msg');
       };
    }
</script>
```

And then your link becomes

```
<a href="javascript:doOnClick();">click</a>
```

Of course, this doesn't feel much simpler with only one function but it helps you put all your functions in the same place and make lighter and clearer html.

---

An alternative would be to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com), so that you may totally avoid putting javascript in the html part.

The html is then

```
<a id=myLink>click</a>
```

And your script, now at the end of the body, is this one :

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#myLink').click(function(){
           if (window.confirm('Really?')){
               __doPostBack('id','msg');
           };
       });

       // other codes will come here
   });
</script>
```

You're not at all required to code it this way now, as you only have a very light function, but if your code grows I suggest you start considering it and look at the jquery tutorials.

Comment: thanks i want to write multi line in javascript like this
'<a href="javascript:a=2;if(confirm('sdsd'))__doPostBack('id','START_EDIT');"> 
click
</a>'

is it possible?

if i click cancel it behaves some thing weird

Comment: I added a lot of comments in my answer. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Here is a small snippet, not elegant but it works...

```
<a href="javascript:if(confirm('Do you really want to post?')) {__doPostBack('id','msg');};">click</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had to look this up because I haven't used `confirm`, `alert` and `prompt` in a very long time.

`confirm` returns true/false depening on what the user selected (OK/Cancel, respectively).

So your resulting code would be

```
<a href="javascript:if (confirm('Are you sure?')) __doPostBack('id','msg');">click</a>
```